# How to achieve similar transition?

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview, swift4, transition, ios-animations

So [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/72907227/Social-Meet-Up-UI-Kit-FREE-for-Adobe-XD) is the example I’m trying to recreate.

Top section is UICollectionView I believe.

But I am confused by lower rows transition.

So what is the easiest way to implement the same transition animation?

Is it custom reload row animation or `tableView.reloadData()`, or may be it is tweaked UICollectionView page switching animation?

Would love to get a code hint also.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the menu could be a collection view but I am guessing that most of it is completely custom.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, but but lower rows? I think it is sort of tableView.reloadRows animation. If it is, then how to shape tableView cells like that?

Comment: I don't think so. I am pretty sure it's completely custom, maybe not a table view at all but a custom component. It could be probably achieved using custom collection view layout but I would guess that using custom components it would be simpler.